Solution suggested to "Distance from a point to a plane" problem in test might be wrong
This is from an application exam. What you see in the image is the answer they gave for a question I disagree with.

My answer is $\frac{10}{3}$ using  $$\text{Distance}=\frac{\left|A x_0+B y_0+C z_0+D\right|}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2+C^2}}$$
Is it a mistake in the answer or I am missing something

The reference answer is obviously wrong, the point is not inside the plane. It was probably intended to have the constant term $5$ with a minus sign, but this was messed up in the task design (or someone got too clever when computing the reference solution).
